# Implementing a Generative RNN with continuous input and discrete output

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently using a generative RNN to classify indices in a sequence (sort of saying whether something is noise or not noise).

My input in continuous (i.e. a real value between 0 and 1) and my output is either a (0 or 1).

For example, if the model marks a 1 for numbers greater than 0.5 and 0 otherwise,

`[.21, .35, .78, .56, ..., .21] => [0, 0, 1, 1, ..., 0]:`

```
   0     0     1     1          0
   ^     ^     ^     ^          ^
   |     |     |     |          |
o->L1  ->L2  ->L3  ->L4 ->... ->L10
   ^     ^     ^     ^          ^
   |     |     |     |          |
   .21  .35   .78   .56   ...  .21
```

Using

```py
n_steps = 10
n_inputs = 1
n_neurons = 7
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_outputs])

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons, activation=tf.nn.relu)
rnn_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
```

rnn_outputs becomes a (?, 10, 7) shape tensor, presumable 7 outputs per each of the 10 time steps.

Previously, I have run the following snippet on output projection wrapped `rnn_outputs` to get a classification label per sequence.

```py
xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,logits=logits)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)
```

How would I run something similar on rnn_outputs to get a sequence?

Specifically,

**1. Can I get the rnn_output from each step and feed it into a softmax?**

```py
curr_state = rnn_outputs[:,i,:]
logits = tf.layers.dense(states, n_outputs)
xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits)
```

**2. What loss function should I use and should it be applied across every value of every sequence?** (for sequence *i* and step *j*, `loss = y_{ij} (true) - y_{ij}(predicted)` )?

Should my loss be `loss = tf.reduce_mean(np.sum(xentropy))`?

**EDIT**
It seems I am trying to implement something similar to what is similar in https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-bidirectional-lstm-sequence-classification-python-keras/ in TensorFlow.

In Keras, there's a `TimeDistributed` function:

> You can then use TimeDistributed to apply a Dense layer to each of the
>   10 timesteps, independently

How would I go about implementing something similar in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, it looks like you're doing seq-to-seq modelling. In this kind of problems it's usually a good idea to go with encoder-decoder architecture rather than predict the sequence from the same RNN. Tensorflow has a big tutorial about it under the name ["Neural Machine Translation (seq2seq) Tutorial"](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt), which I'd recommend you to check out.

However, the architecture that you're asking about is also possible provided that `n_steps` is known *statically* (despite using `dynamic_rnn`). In this case, it's possible compute the cross-entropy of each cells' output and then sum up all the losses. It's possible if the RNN length is dynamic as well, but would be more hairy. Here's the code:

```py
n_steps = 2
n_inputs = 3
n_neurons = 5

X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, n_steps, n_inputs], name='x')
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, n_steps], name='y')
basic_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons)
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)

# Reshape to make `time` a 0-axis
time_based_outputs = tf.transpose(outputs, [1, 0, 2])
time_based_labels = tf.transpose(y, [1, 0])
losses = []
for i in range(n_steps):
  cell_output = time_based_outputs[i]   # get the output, can do apply further dense layers if needed
  labels = time_based_labels[i]         # get the label (sparse)
  loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=cell_output)
  losses.append(loss)                   # collect all losses
total_loss = tf.reduce_sum(losses)      # compute the total loss
```